# Check if post/page has gallery?

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I'd like to run some code only if a gallery (inserted with the `[gallery]` shortcode) has been inserted into a post/page. I did the following:

```
gallery_shortcode($post->ID) ?
$gallery = 1 : $gallery = 0;
```

However, this always sets `$gallery = 0` whether there's a gallery or not. Am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: Normally that should be (no matter if it's working or not): `$gallery = gallery_shortcode($post->ID) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try :

```
if (strpos($post->post_content,'[gallery') === false){
  $gallery = 0;
}else{
  $gallery = 1;
}
```

Comment: Just to make that (more) clear for later readers: `0` = `false` & `1` = `true`

Comment: Isn't it a kind of resource hog checking through lots of (probably) big texts for the occurence of [gallery ?

Comment: @vlood Strpos is the fastest function there is when it comes to searching strings and not big on resources so that's not an issue.

Comment: I was thinking of comparing strpos with something on database side... If you got a website with lot's of visitors daily and for some reason you don't have caching enabled, filtering posts on the query might be a lot better than doing that in the php code.

Comment: Great, I added this to functions.php for re-use: `function hasgallery(){global $post;return (strpos($post->post_content,'[gallery') !== false);}`

Answer (score 3):

My iteration on the suggested solution here, is the following function in my theme's functions.php:

```
function has_gallery($post_id = false) {
    if (!$post_id) {
        global $post;
    } else {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
    }
    return ( strpos($post->post_content,'[gallery') !== false); 
}
```

Which I can then call in a template file (doesn't care about The Loop):

```
$has_gallery = has_gallery($post_id) ? true : false;
```

or more direct:

```
has_gallery($post_id); //will evaluate to true/false
```

`$post_id` is optional, the following will ***only*** work within The Loop:

```
has_gallery();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using the `get_post_gallery()` function. This is exactly the way, most themes are checking if a post has a gallery to print the correct body CSS classes:

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) {
    // run your code in here
}
```

P.S. I really don't like solutions that search the whole content for anything, even if string functions are typically quite fast in PHP, it's still a huge performance overhead.

Comment: If you look into the code, `get_post_gallery` calls `get_post_galleries` which calls `has_shortcode` which does a `strpos` and some more... Doing a `strpos` from the start is way faster.

Comment: That's correct. In terms of perfomance, the accepted answer is faster. But someone might have used another shortcode for galleries that hooks into the `get_post_gallery()` function. Therefore this solution would always work and there is also no need to implement an additional function.