# Check if a different page has any attached images

Tags: functions, gallery

I am trying to make a notification function for a user's account dashboard that displays if they have not added any images to their profile's gallery. I found this page, which is a function that checks if the CURRENT page has any attachments:
[Check if post/page has gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20218/check-if-post-page-has-gallery)

How can I change that to check by a specific post ID, i.e. a function that will check if post 2 has a gallery or not?

Comment: the code you linked checks if the post content contains the [gallery shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode), which is not the same as checking if a post has any attached images. a post can have attached images without containing the gallery shortcode. please clarify which you want to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post_id
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    echo "attachments rock!";
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure the atachements are an image, you would use:

```
if ( $attachments and wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) ) {
echo "attachments rock!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not getting the proper result on this.Here is what I put in : function gallerycheck_func(){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => 2
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ( $attachments and wp_attachment_is_image( 2 ) )
{echo '<p style="text-align:center;">Your profile looks good!</p>';}else{
echo '<p style="text-align:center;">You need to add atleast one photo to your profile!</p>';
}}
add_shortcode( 'gallerycheck', 'gallerycheck_func' );

Comment: Okay it worked perfectly with just the top part, thanks! It was the and wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) which seems to be misfiring. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to that question you mentioned, you need to the have the post content in order to check if there is a gallery assigned to it. The function `get_post` is what you need.

```
$my_post = get_post($some_post_id);
if (strpos($my_post->post_content,'[gallery') === false){
  $gallery = 0;
}else{
  $gallery = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure if this will work because I don't actually use the [gallery] shortcode in my page template? I tried this, but wasn't getting a result

Comment: like Milo pointed out above, I misspoke stating I was checking for the shortcode, I should have said I was checking if their were images IN the gallery, thanks you anyway