# How to determine if a post has attached images?

Tags: gallery

I would like to know how I can determine if a post/page has an image gallery (not documents/videos etc)?
I am not talking about gallery shortcode as shown here [Check if post/page has gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20218/check-if-post-page-has-gallery)

so that

```
if (has_gallery = true){

  //Do Something
}

else {
  // Do Something else
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: "if a post has *images* **attached** to it"? .... If so, please edit the Question to make this clear.

Comment: I meant gallery attached to it... people can attach images to via WYSIWYG to the actual post... but I want to actually determine if post has a gallery...?

Comment: In WordPress parlance "*gallery*" = "*images attached to a post*".

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get_posts` and search for image attachments.

```
<?php
$images = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent'    => $the_parent_to_check, // whatever this is
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', // attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // only image attachments
    'post_status'    => 'inherit', // attachments have this status
));

if($images)
{
     // has images
}
else
{
     // no images. :(
}
```

Might be more efficient to write a custom SQL query to check for the count. Depends on whether you want to do something with the attachment posts or not.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a post has a gallery write a small helper function:

```
function has_gallery( $post = NULL )
{
    if ( ! is_null( $post ) )
        $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( ! $post )
    {
        if ( ! isset ( $GLOBALS['post'] ) )
            return FALSE;

        $post = $GLOBALS['post'];
    }

    return FALSE !== strpos( $post->post_content, '[gallery' );
}
```

Usage:

```
if ( has_gallery() ) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Note that a post with a gallery doesn’t necessary has attachments: You can create a gallery with images that are attached to other posts.

Comment: From the question "I am not talking about gallery shortcode"

Comment: Hm, then I misread _I meant gallery attached to it_ … contradictory description.