# Checking for 'gallery' shortcode using strpos always returns false

Tags: gallery, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags, wp-enqueue-style

I want to conditionally enqueue a script and stylesheet depending on whether the `[gallery]` shortcode is used in posts. Here is how I am doing it ([based on](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20219)):

```
function doraemon_scripts() {

    if( is_single() ) {

        if (strpos($post->post_content,'[gallery') === false){
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( ... );
            wp_enqueue_script( ... );
        }

    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'doraemon_scripts' );
```

But the problem is, the stylesheet and script aren't being enqueued, as it seems, `strpos` is always returning false. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `global $post` to get the `$post` variable into the scope of that function.

```
function doraemon_scripts() {

    if( is_single() ) {
      global $post;
        if (strpos($post->post_content,'[gallery') === false){
        } else {
//             wp_enqueue_style( ... );
//             wp_enqueue_script( ... );
        }

    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'doraemon_scripts' );
```

Using the `$post` global outside of the Loop is not always reliable, but WordPress will set that variable to the first post in the result set which will be the correct post on *single* post pages, but won't be right on other pages.

Of course, that won't work if something else has altered the global, and you can't always predict what a plugin will do and where.

You might be safer using ...

```
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->posts[0];
```